# Why would WPF / Entity Framework give me a AspNetHostingPermission error when reading .MDF file?

Tags: wpf, security, entity-framework

I have a **WPF** application which uses **LINQ-to-SQL** to access an .**MDF** file within its local directory structure. This works **fine**.

However, when I create a **second .MDF** file in the **same directory** as the first, and try to create a model with **Entity Framework**, it gives me this **error**:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission'

**What kind of extra settings to I have to make so that the Entity Framework classes can access a local .MDF file as does the LINQ-to-SQL classes?**

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: there is a link on the error box that says "add permissions to this application", you just have to click it and restart.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a trust issue.  It may be related to how you refer to the MDF in the Entity Framework with regards to path.  If that's the case be sure to use the ~ to refer to the relative MDF path so that it resolves as the trust-level expects.